# Sort two-dimensional NSMutableArray using the last element the inner arrays

Tags: sorting, nsmutablearray

I have the following NSMutableArray:

```
 (A|B|C|D|E|255,
 F|G|H|I|J|122,
 K|L|M|N|O|555)
```

I am trying to sort the objects in the array using the last component (255, 122, 555). Right now I have the following code:

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

As expected, this method sorts the array by the first element (A, F, K).

I also read about NSSortDescriptor, for example:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateModified" ascending:YES] autorelease];
```

If I use it, it is not clear what I put as a parameter in `initWithKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a sort descriptor, which takes the last object of the "inner" arrays and sort by that.

Since sort descriptors use key-value coding (KVC), you need to be aware that arrays respond to `valueForKey:` in a special way - they pass a normal key on to each of the objects that they contain.

You also need to know that methods which do *not* take a parameter *and* return a value can be accessed through KVC is if they were normal properties.

All this adds up to the following:

1. Each of the objects contained in your array (i.e., the inner arrays) have a key that you want to sort by: `lastObject`
2. But since the objects are instances of `NSArray` they will normally pass the key on to the objects that *they* contain - which is not what you want.
3. You therefore need to use a special escape in the key name for that situation, which is `@`, making the actual key to use `@lastObject`

So to make a long story short, you can do what you want in this way:

```
NSMutableArray *array = ... // Your array

NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"@lastObject"
                                                     ascending: YES 
                                                      selector: @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[array sortUsingDescriptors: @[sd]];
```

You'll notice the "@" in the key name, within the string.

This escape character also works for other collection classes, for instance if you want to access `allKeys` from a dictionary through KVC, the key you should use is `@allKeys`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use sortUsingComparator:

```
[myArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
    return [obj1.lastPropertyForComparison compare:obj2.lastPropertyForComparison];
}
```

This method allows you to manually compare the properties or members of the objects that you want to order by. I use it almost exclusively for complex sorts, and I haven't noticed any performance differences.

UPDATE:
If your NSMutableArray contains NSArrays with the last object being the number you're trying to rank by, your comparator would be as follows:

```
[(NSNumber *)[obj1 lastObject] compare:(NSNumber *)[obj2 lastObject]]
```

Basically, you are grabbing the last object out of each NSArray, which you know is an NSNumber. You use the compare function to return NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending, or NSOrderedSame. I hope that helps.

Comment: user2105505, thanks for your help. I am trying to figure out how to use sortUsingComparator in my case. When I use the method objectAtIndex, it treats the whole section as an object (F|G|H|I|J|122, not 122, for example). Thank you!

Comment: It isn't stated in your question, but I assume that F|G|H|I|J|122 is an NSArray. So, you're trying to sort an NSMutableArray containing NSArrays. I updated my question to answer this case.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated!